# Retrieve User ID before application permissions

Tags: facebook, graph

Is it possible to retrieve an user id before agreeing to give permissions to an application?

I'm trying to salute a user before agreeing to the permission request. But for that I'll need to know his/her user id so I can access the info via graph API.

The idea is to do it when he/she is visiting for the first time my page app.
http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **NOT** possible. Facebook **WILL NOT** share the user id with any app without the user explicitly allow that (partners are always a special case).

Comment: And the list of partners who are in that special case are a *very* select few.

Comment: +1, @JimmySawczuk and [here](https://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/) more about it.

Comment: Nice link, I wasn't aware they had a well-designed info page about it anywhere.

Comment: well designed or advertise focused?
it's a pity not to have access to users even from inside facebook itself...

Comment: You need to tag @JimmySawczuk so he can get a notification...and for your question I guess both.

Comment: You're not inside Facebook though, you just appear to be. Giving you a user ID without them installing is a major privacy concern; when companies get access to Instant Personalization (as it's called) those companies work very closely with Facebook to ensure a secure and transparent process.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible.

The only way to get the details of the current user is to issue a request to

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

But here the problem is to get the access token, user should allow the application first.

Comment: I have edited the main thread for better comprehension. Thanks!